# Powershell Automated MKVToolNix DTS Re-order & Convert and Subtitle Cleanup - Plex

Tags: powershell, if-statement, variables, conditional-statements

Running a test on a suggestion; I ran the following code:

```
$CustomScripts = "C:\Program Files\MKVToolNix\Custom Scripts"
$Track1DTS = "Track ID 1: audio (TrueHD Atmos)"
$Track1DTSHD = "Track ID 1: audio (TrueHD Atmos)"
$Track2A = "Track ID 2: audio (AC-3)"

$newvids =
"Track ID 0: video (HEVC/H.265/MPEG-H)
Track ID 1: audio (TrueHD Atmos)
Track ID 2: audio (AC-3)"

($newvids -contains [regex]::Escape($Track1DTS) -xor $newvids -contains [regex]::Escape($Track1DTSHD)) -and ($newvids -match [regex]::Escape($Track2A))
```

which returns "False" the same way as if the values did not match, when it should match and be true.

**-UPDATE2-**

While I was able to get the test to return true and false (Thank you @Mathias R. Jessen.) But it still seems to pickup things wrong on the full script based on the batch output, matching the mkvs I don't want. Below is the full script.

```
$CustomScripts = "C:\Program Files\MKVToolNix\Custom Scripts"
$Track1DTS = "Track ID 1: audio (DTS)"
$Track1DTSHD = "Track ID 1: audio (DTS-HD Master Audio)"
$Track2A = "Track ID 2: audio"

Set-Location -Path 'M:\Movies\'
$oldvids = Get-ChildItem *.mkv -Recurse
foreach ($oldvid in $oldvids) {
$vidpath = mkvmerge.exe -i $oldvid | Select-String -SimpleMatch 'M:\Movies' 
$newvidpath = (([regex]".*'(.*)'").Matches($vidpath))[0].Groups[1].Value
$newVariable = Split-Path $newvidpath -Parent
Set-Location -Path "$newVariable"
$newvids = mkvmerge.exe -i $oldvid
    if(($newvids -match [regex]::Escape($Track1DTS) -xor $newvids -match [regex]::Escape($Track1DTSHD)) -and ($newvids -match [regex]::Escape($Track2A))){PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& '$CustomScripts\DTSReorder.bat'"}
}
```

First output line is:

```
Enumerating all MKVs under "M:\Movies\"
"A Nightmare on Elm Street 3 - Dream Warriors Bluray-1080p.mkv" has no DTS Audio
```

When I check the properties of that file, I find this:

```
C:\Users\Joel>mkvmerge.exe -i "M:Movies\A Nightmare on Elm Street 3 - Dream Warriors (1987)\A Nightmare on Elm Street 3 - Dream Warriors Bluray-1080p.mkv"
File 'M:Movies\A Nightmare on Elm Street 3 - Dream Warriors (1987)\A Nightmare on Elm Street 3 - Dream Warriors Bluray-1080p.mkv': container: Matroska
Track ID 0: video (HEVC/H.265/MPEG-H)
Track ID 1: audio (AAC)
Track ID 2: audio (AAC)
Attachment ID 1: type 'image/jpeg', size 245498 bytes, file name 'cover.jpeg'
Chapters: 32 entries
```

So why is it matching that movie file; when it shouldn't be based on the variables provided in the conditions.

**-UPDATE3-**

Poking more at it, I recreated the script but instead of actioning a bat file on a match I just made it print the match and match location. The test script looks like this:

```
$CustomScripts = "C:\Program Files\MKVToolNix\Custom Scripts"
$Track1DTS = "Track ID 1: audio (DTS)"
$Track1DTSHD = "Track ID 1: audio (DTS-HD Master Audio)"
$Track2A = "Track ID 2: audio"

Set-Location -Path 'M:\Movies\'
$oldvids = Get-ChildItem *.mkv -Recurse
foreach ($oldvid in $oldvids) {
$vidpath = mkvmerge.exe -i $oldvid | Select-String -SimpleMatch 'M:\Movies' 
$newvidpath = (([regex]".*'(.*)'").Matches($vidpath))[0].Groups[1].Value
$newVariable = Split-Path $newvidpath -Parent
Set-Location -Path "$newVariable"
$newvids = mkvmerge.exe -i $oldvid
    if(($newvids -match [regex]::Escape($Track1DTS) -xor $newvids -match [regex]::Escape($Track1DTSHD)) -and ($newvids -match [regex]::Escape($Track2A))){echo match $newVariable}
}

Set-Location -Path 'M:\Movies\'
$oldvideos = Get-ChildItem *.mkv -Recurse
foreach ($oldvid2 in $oldvideos) {
$vidpath2 = mkvmerge.exe -i $oldvid2 | Select-String -SimpleMatch 'M:\Movies' 
$newvidpath2 = (([regex]".*'(.*)'").Matches($vidpath2))[0].Groups[1].Value
$newVariable2 = Split-Path $newvidpath2 -Parent
Set-Location -Path "$newVariable2"
$newtracks = mkvmerge.exe -i $oldvid2 | Select-String -SimpleMatch "Track ID 2"
    if($newtracks -eq $null){echo match $newVariable2}
}
```

The output looks like this:

```
match

match
M:\Movies\Ace Ventura - Pet Detective (1994)
match

match
M:\Movies\Good Boys (2019)
match
M:\Movies\Gremlins (1984)
match
M:\Movies\Guns Akimbo (2019)
match
M:\Movies\Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows - Part 1 (2010)
match
M:\Movies\Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix (2007)
match
M:\Movies\Hell or High Water (2016)
match
M:\Movies\Horizon Line (2020)
```

It eventually straightens itself out when it runs for a while, and starts only reporting matches with paths; and when I check those matches they are accurate; but the first few matches are wrong when I throw it at the batch. Not sure why; because even when I ask it to echo the match, doesn't tell me what matched for those first few lines. It just says "match"

**-UPDATE 4-**

I am done, everything is functional. It now runs something like;

1. It checks to see if an MKV file has DTS;
2. If not it just skips to the end for a subtitle check and removal.
3. If it has DTS and it's the only codec, it starts a transcode to EAC3.
   (But leaving the original incase you want to use it or go back. Also removes the subtitles at the same time so you don't waste time recoding twice.)
4. If there is another Codec file available, it does a reorder instead, making it the default codec.
   (But leaving the original incase you want to use it or go back. Also removes the subtitles at the same time so you don't waste time recoding twice.)
5. It has a final check for subs for any movies that didn't hit the first 2 matches.

It does seem to still randomly mismatch for the first 2-3 checks of the PowerShell, but that is okay seeing the bat files it calls have their own secondary check before continuing... (Consider it a backup for the first few possible mismatches seeing I can't figure out what's causing that bug/hiccup.)

The final PowerShell script is looking like this:

```
    ##MKV Audio Track Values to Search in Files##
    
    $CustomScripts = "C:\Program Files\MKVToolNix\Custom Scripts"
    $Track1DTS = "Track ID 1: audio (DTS)"
    $Track1DTSHD = "Track ID 1: audio (DTS-HD Master Audio)"
    $Track2DTS = "Track ID 2: audio (DTS)"
    $Track2DTSHD = "Track ID 2: audio (DTS-HD Master Audio)"
            
    ##DTS Search and Reorder & Replace Code##
    
    Set-Location -Path 'M:\Movies\'
    $oldvids = Get-ChildItem *.mkv -Recurse
    foreach ($oldvid in $oldvids) {
    $vidpath = mkvmerge.exe -i $oldvid | Select-String -SimpleMatch 'M:\Movies' 
    $newvidpath = (([regex]".*'(.*)'").Matches($vidpath))[0].Groups[1].Value
    $newVariable = Split-Path $newvidpath -Parent
    Set-Location -Path "$newVariable"
    $newvids = mkvmerge.exe -i $oldvid
        if(($newvids -match [regex]::Escape($Track1DTS) -xor $newvids -match [regex]::Escape($Track1DTSHD)) -and ($newvids -notmatch [regex]::Escape($Track2DTS) -xor $newvids -match [regex]::Escape($Track2DTSHD))){& $CustomScripts\DTSReorder.bat}
    }
    Set-Location -Path 'M:\Movies\'
    get-childitem -Path * *.AudioTrackReordered.mkv -Recurse | foreach { rename-item $_ $_.Name.Replace(".AudioTrackReordered", "") }
    
    $oldvids = Get-ChildItem *.mkv -Recurse
    foreach ($oldvid in $oldvids) {
    $vidpath = mkvmerge.exe -i $oldvid | Select-String -SimpleMatch 'M:\Movies' 
    $newvidpath = (([regex]".*'(.*)'").Matches($vidpath))[0].Groups[1].Value
    $newVariable = Split-Path $newvidpath -Parent
    Set-Location -Path "$newVariable"
    $newvids = mkvmerge.exe -i $oldvid
        if(($newvids -match [regex]::Escape($Track1DTS) -xor $newvids -match [regex]::Escape($Track1DTSHD)) -and ($newvids -match [regex]::Escape($Track2DTSHD) -xor $newvids -match [regex]::Escape($Track2DTS))){& $CustomScripts\DTSConvert.bat}
    }
    Set-Location -Path 'M:\Movies\'
    get-childitem -Path * *.EACConverted.mkv -Recurse | foreach { rename-item $_ $_.Name.Replace(".EACConverted", "") }
    
    Set-Location -Path 'M:\Movies\'
    $oldvids = Get-ChildItem *.mkv -Recurse
    foreach ($oldvid in $oldvids) {
    $vidpath = mkvmerge.exe -i $oldvid | Select-String -SimpleMatch 'M:\Movies' 
    $newvidpath = (([regex]".*'(.*)'").Matches($vidpath))[0].Groups[1].Value
    $newVariable = Split-Path $newvidpath -Parent
    Set-Location -Path "$newVariable"
    $newvids = mkvmerge.exe -i $oldvid | Select-String -SimpleMatch 'Track ID 2' 
        if($newvids -eq $null){& $CustomScripts\DTSConvert.bat}
    }
    Set-Location -Path 'M:\Movies\'
    get-childitem -Path * *.EACConverted.mkv -Recurse | foreach { rename-item $_ $_.Name.Replace(".EACConverted", "") }
    
    
    ##Subtitle Search & Remove Code##
    
    $oldvids = Get-ChildItem *.mkv -Recurse
    foreach ($oldvid in $oldvids) {
    $vidpath = mkvmerge.exe -i $oldvid | Select-String -SimpleMatch 'M:\Movies' 
    $newvidpath = (([regex]".*'(.*)'").Matches($vidpath))[0].Groups[1].Value
    $newVariable = Split-Path $newvidpath -Parent
    Set-Location -Path "$newVariable"
    $newvids =

 mkvmerge.exe -i $oldvid
    if($newvids -match "subtitles"){& $CustomScripts\DelMKVSubs.bat}
    }
    Set-Location -Path 'M:\Movies\'
    get-childitem -Path * *.NoSubs.mkv -Recurse | foreach { rename-item $_ $_.Name.Replace(".NoSubs", "") }
    exit
```

Batch files it calls look like this:

DTSReorder.bat

```
@echo off
cls
set rootfolder="M:\Movies\"
echo Enumerating all MKVs under %rootfolder%
echo.
for %%a in (*.mkv) do (
    for /f %%b in ('mkvmerge -i "%%a" ^| find /c /i "DTS"') do (
        if [%%b]==[0] (
            echo "%%a" has no DTS Audio
        ) else (
            echo.
            echo "%%a" has DTS Audio
            mkvmerge -q -o "%%~dpna.AudioTrackReordered%%~xa" -S "%%a" --track-order 0:0,0:2,0:1
            if errorlevel 1 (
                echo Warnings/errors generated during remuxing, original file not deleted
            ) else (
                del /f "%%a"
                echo Successfully remuxed to "%%~dpna.AudioTrackReordered%%~xa", original file deleted
            )
            echo.
        )
    )
)
```

DTSConvert.bat

```
@echo off
cls
set rootfolder="M:\Movies\"
echo Enumerating all MKVs under %rootfolder%
echo.
for %%a in (*.mkv) do (
    for /f %%b in ('mkvmerge -i "%%a" ^| find /c /i "DTS"') do (
        if [%%b]==[0] (
            echo "%%a" has no DTS Audio
        ) else (
            echo.
            echo "%%a" has DTS Audio
            ffmpeg -i "%%a" -map 0:v -map 0:a:0 -map 0:a -c:v copy -c:a copy -c:a:0 eac3 -b:a:0 640k "%%~dpna.EACConverted%%~xa"
            if errorlevel 1 (
                echo Warnings/errors generated during remuxing, original file not deleted
            ) else (
                del /f "%%a"
                echo Successfully remuxed to "%%~dpna.EACConverted%%~xa", original file deleted
            )
            echo.
        )
    )
)
```

DelMKVSubs.Bat

```
@echo off
cls
set rootfolder="M:\Movies\"
echo Enumerating all MKVs under %rootfolder%
echo.
for %%a in (*.mkv) do (
    for /f %%b in ('mkvmerge -i "%%a" ^| find /c /i "subtitles"') do (
        if [%%b]==[0] (
            echo "%%a" has no subtitles
        ) else (
            echo.
            echo "%%a" has subtitles
            mkvmerge -q -o "%%~dpna.NoSubs%%~xa" -S "%%a"
            if errorlevel 1 (
                echo Warnings/errors generated during remuxing, original file not deleted
            ) else (
                del /f "%%a"
           

 echo Successfully remuxed to "%%~dpna.NoSubs%%~xa", original file deleted
        )
        echo.
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: `-contains` will only return true is an _exact_ match is found in `$newvids`. Try `($newvids -match [regex]::Escape($Track1DTS)) -xor ($newvids -match [regex]::Escape($Track1DTSHD))`

Comment: The final condition needs to be absolute for the .bat file to run, while the first two is a one or the other situation. But it has to match the whole string exactly. The problem with the final condition is that it has to include: "Track ID 2: audio" I just don't know what codec it will use after that. It could be Track ID 2: audio (DTS) or Track ID 2: audio (DTS-HD) or Track ID 2: audio (AC3) etc.

Comment: Are you sure? `($newvids -match [regex]::Escape($Track1DTS) -xor $newvids -match [regex]::Escape($Track1DTSHD)) -and ($newvids -match [regex]::Escape($Track2A))` returns `$false` (as expected) for the input you've provided when I try

Comment: `$CustomScripts = "C:\Program Files\MKVToolNix\Custom Scripts"
$Track1DTS = "Track ID 1: audio (AAC)"
$Track1DTSHD = "Track ID 1: audio (AAC)"
$Track2A = "Track ID 2: audio"

$newvids = "
Track ID 0: video (HEVC/H.265/MPEG-H)
Track ID 1: audio (AAC)
Track ID 2: audio (AAC)

($newvids -match [regex]::Escape($Track1DTS) -xor $newvids -match [regex]::Escape($Track1DTSHD)) -and ($newvids -match [regex]::Escape($Track2A))` This returns false for me as well in a test, but I can confirm it matches incorrectly. If I change the values for `$Track1DTS` in the test, it still matches false.

Comment: If you change the value to _what_? Please [update your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70531648/edit) with these details :)

Comment: Post updated with latest test! :) Thanks for your time!

Comment: You've set the `$Track1DTS` and `$Track1DTSHD` to the same value, so the first two `-match` operations will return either both `$true` or both `$false`, and the `-xor` operation therefore always resolves to `$false`

Comment: Thank you for that! You are correct that was my bad in the test, but I can confirm it still does not function correctly in the full script. I will update the post with the full script if condition now.

Comment: Updated again. Thanks for your time. I can confirm the testing now works and says true, but the full script continues to mismatch. I dumped it in the original post for your review.

Comment: Where does the output come from? Nothing in your code writes "Enumerating all MKVs" or "has no DTS Audio" anywhere

Comment: It comes from the .bat file which the PowerShell code calls for when a match is made as found above: `{PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& '$CustomScripts\DTSReorder.bat'"}` It shouldn't run that without a match being made.

Comment: The .bat file has a secondary check, which as you can tell it fails because Powershell is matching stuff incorrectly, if it was then the file would have DTS and both the PowerShell and .bat file would comply and move forwards. In that case the .bat file is reporting an issue, when I check I confirm that the Powershell ran the .bat file when the match shouldn't have been made.

Comment: Interesting enough, it seems that if I change the action to `echo match $newVariable` so it does an echo on a match with file path that matched. But the first few lines are still problematic. I am not sure why. It eventually straightens itself out when it runs for a while, but the first few matches are wrong. Not sure why because even the echo the match doesn't tell me what matched for those first few lines. It just says `match

match
M:\Movies\Ace Ventura - Pet Detective (1994)
match

match
M:\Movies\Good Boys (2019)
match
M:\Movies\Gremlins (1984)
match
M:\Movies\Guns Akimbo (19)`

Answer (score 0):

Everything is functional. It now runs something like;

1. It checks to see if an MKV file has DTS;
2. If not it just skips to the end for a subtitle check and removal.
3. If it has DTS and it's the only codec, it starts a transcode to EAC3.
   (But leaving the original incase you want to use it or go back. Also removes the subtitles at the same time so you don't waste time recoding twice.)
4. If there is another Codec file available, it does a reorder instead, making it the default codec.
   (But leaving the original incase you want to use it or go back. Also removes the subtitles at the same time so you don't waste time recoding twice.)
5. It has a final check for subs for any movies that didn't hit the first 2 matches.

It does seem to still randomly mismatch for the first 2-3 checks of the Powershell, but that is okay seeing the bat files it calls have their own secondary check before continuing... (Consider it a backup for the first few possible mismatches seeing I can't figure out what's causing that bug/hiccup.)

The final PowerShell script is looking like this:

```
##MKV Audio Track Values to Search in Files##

$CustomScripts = "C:\Program Files\MKVToolNix\Custom Scripts"
$Track1DTS = "Track ID 1: audio (DTS)"
$Track1DTSHD = "Track ID 1: audio (DTS-HD Master Audio)"
$Track2DTS = "Track ID 2: audio (DTS)"
$Track2DTSHD = "Track ID 2: audio (DTS-HD Master Audio)"  

##DTS Search and Reorder & Replace Code##

Set-Location -Path 'M:\Movies\'
$oldvids = Get-ChildItem *.mkv -Recurse
foreach ($oldvid in $oldvids) {
$vidpath = mkvmerge.exe -i $oldvid | Select-String -SimpleMatch 'M:\Movies' 
$newvidpath = (([regex]".*'(.*)'").Matches($vidpath))[0].Groups[1].Value
$newVariable = Split-Path $newvidpath -Parent
Set-Location -Path "$newVariable"
$newvids = mkvmerge.exe -i $oldvid
    if(($newvids -match [regex]::Escape($Track1DTS) -xor $newvids -match [regex]::Escape($Track1DTSHD)) -and ($newvids -notmatch [regex]::Escape($Track2DTS) -xor $newvids -match [regex]::Escape($Track2DTSHD))){& $CustomScripts\DTSReorder.bat}
}
Set-Location -Path 'M:\Movies\'
get-childitem -Path * *.AudioTrackReordered.mkv -Recurse | foreach { rename-item $_ $_.Name.Replace(".AudioTrackReordered", "") }

$oldvids = Get-ChildItem *.mkv -Recurse
foreach ($oldvid in $oldvids) {
$vidpath = mkvmerge.exe -i $oldvid | Select-String -SimpleMatch 'M:\Movies' 
$newvidpath = (([regex]".*'(.*)'").Matches($vidpath))[0].Groups[1].Value
$newVariable = Split-Path $newvidpath -Parent
Set-Location -Path "$newVariable"
$newvids = mkvmerge.exe -i $oldvid
    if(($newvids -match [regex]::Escape($Track1DTS) -xor $newvids -match [regex]::Escape($Track1DTSHD)) -and ($newvids -match [regex]::Escape($Track2DTSHD) -xor $newvids -match [regex]::Escape($Track2DTS))){& $CustomScripts\DTSConvert.bat}
}
Set-Location -Path 'M:\Movies\'
get-childitem -Path * *.EACConverted.mkv -Recurse | foreach { rename-item $_ $_.Name.Replace(".EACConverted", "") }

Set-Location -Path 'M:\Movies\'
$oldvids = Get-ChildItem *.mkv -Recurse
foreach ($oldvid in $oldvids) {
$vidpath = mkvmerge.exe -i $oldvid | Select-String -SimpleMatch 'M:\Movies' 
$newvidpath = (([regex]".*'(.*)'").Matches($vidpath))[0].Groups[1].Value
$newVariable = Split-Path $newvidpath -Parent
Set-Location -Path "$newVariable"
$newvids = mkvmerge.exe -i $oldvid | Select-String -SimpleMatch 'Track ID 2' 
    if($newvids -eq $null){& $CustomScripts\DTSConvert.bat}
}
Set-Location -Path 'M:\Movies\'
get-childitem -Path * *.EACConverted.mkv -Recurse | foreach { rename-item $_ $_.Name.Replace(".EACConverted", "") }


##Subtitle Search & Remove Code##

$oldvids = Get-ChildItem *.mkv -Recurse
foreach ($oldvid in $oldvids) {
$vidpath = mkvmerge.exe -i $oldvid | Select-String -SimpleMatch 'M:\Movies' 
$newvidpath = (([regex]".*'(.*)'").Matches($vidpath))[0].Groups[1].Value
$newVariable = Split-Path $newvidpath -Parent
Set-Location -Path "$newVariable"
$newvids = mkvmerge.exe -i $oldvid
    if($newvids -match "subtitles"){& $CustomScripts\DelMKVSubs.bat}
}
Set-Location -Path 'M:\Movies\'
get-childitem -Path * *.NoSubs.mkv -Recurse | foreach { rename-item $_ $_.Name.Replace(".NoSubs", "") }
exit
```